# Sourcing workspace generated by a catkin_make install

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### I'm trying to distribute a binary version of my package. I have the `catkin_make install` command create the `install` directory in the right place and copy the required libs. The contents of the `install` directory are as follows:
include

### (contains exported packages with generated header files for messages)
lib

### (contains 3rd party dependencies as well as exported packages with executables)
share

(contains exported packages with misc. files such as package.xml)

My problem is that when I copy this directory to a new computer, I can't use ROS to run anything from it. I tried doing the following on the new machine within the distributed `install` directory:

- Create a `src` directory
- Run `catkin_init_workspace`
- Run `catkin_make` to generate the `devel` and `build` directories
- Source the generated `devel/setup.bash` script

`rosrun my_package my_package_node` still doesn't find my package. What can I do to get ROS to see my installed packages the way packages in /opt/ros/indigo work?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230072/sourcing-workspace-generated-by-a-catkin_make-install/) by [autonomy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3784/autonomy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 435 on 2016-03-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You cannot use the `devel` folder as a redistributable, as it also references the `src` folder. Do this instead:

- create a `src` directory (and fill it with your code)
- run `catkin_make install` (`catkin_init_workspace` isn't necessary as `catkin_make` will do it implicitly)
- copy/archive the `install` folder and move it to a new computer

And it should work so long as you have any dependencies that were not in the workspace installed.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2016-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [autonomy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3784/autonomy/) on 2016-03-24**:
That's essentially what I did (catkin_make_install and copied the install directory). But I can't use rosrun/roslaunch with my install folder on the new computer - it doesn't find the packages/launch files.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2016-03-24**:
It is `catkin_make install` not `catkin_make_install` and your question doesn't describe the install folder at all... If you're copying the install folder and it still isn't working then we'll need more information. Did you source the setup file in the install folder after copying it over?

**Comment by [autonomy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3784/autonomy/) on 2016-03-24**:
Well yeah, it's a typo, there's no such command as `catkin_make_install`. And what do you mean my question "doesn't describe the install folder" - is it supposed to be different from what I did list? Mine only contains include, lib, and share directories. There is no setup file anywhere.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2016-03-24**:
Your question only mentions the `devel` folder, which is not the same as the `install` folder.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2016-03-24**:
"Source the generated devel/setup.bash script"

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2016-03-24**:
If your `install` folder doesn't contain a `setup.*sh` file then I'd have to guess your workspace doesn't contain a catkin package.

**Comment by [autonomy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3784/autonomy/) on 2016-03-24**:
Yeah, my install folder **does not** contain anything but *include*, *lib*, and *share* dirs. I'm attempting to generate the *devel* dir and *setup.bash* scripts by running `catkin_init_workspace` in the install directory on the new machine. So you think my package is not catkinized correctly?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-03-24**:
If your `install` space has no `setup.bash`, then it was never created correctly.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-03-24**:
@autonomy: can you add the contents of your `CMakeLists.txt` to your OP? Do you have a `catkin_package(..)` statement in there somewhere?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2016-03-24**:
How did you create your install folder? by running `catkin_make install`? We don't seem to be on the same page in our terminology, have you had a look at http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0128.html?

**Comment by [vacky11](https://answers.ros.org/users/29229/vacky11/) on 2018-01-09**:
Along with all the steps mentioned in the answer above, add the following line in your .bashrc file

```
source ~/catkin_ws/install/setup.bash
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-09**:
@vacky11: but only if you actually have `catkin_make` install packages into the *install space*. Otherwise the line you show does nothing.